# Parameter is not valid using Private bitmap

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I'm trying to create a new Bitmap within a method using a Private bitmap created outside the method, but it's throwing a parameter is not valid error. I'm fairly new to C# so can anyone have a scan and see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```
    private Bitmap picture;
    private Graphics g1;
    private Cursor c1, c2;
    public HSBColor HSBcol = new HSBColor();
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        init();
        start();
        mandelbrot();

    }

    public void init() // all instances will be prepared
    {                 
        finished = false;
        x1 = this.Location.X;
        y1 = this.Location.Y; 
        xy = (float)x1 / (float)y1;
        picture = new Bitmap(x1, y1);
        g1 = Graphics.FromImage(picture);
        finished = true;
    }
```

Comment: are `x1` and `y1` greater than zero?

Comment: `Bitmap(int, int)` defines the size, not the location, so you should not be using location properties to define it. Take a look at the parameter names, its not X and Y but Width and Height.

Comment: Cheers guys, been bugging me for ages. I just manually set x1 and y1 to the co-ordinates. not entirely sure why I didnt do this in the first place haha